# PHP replace include with html block

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I am attempting to use PHP to parse a .php file, find any `<?php include $root.'whatever.html'; ?>` and replace with a block of html code.

So far I'm running into two problems, how to capture the whatever.html into a variable and for it not to treat the $root variable as local reference.

Comment: use file_get_contents to capture html into variable

Comment: You can start to learn regex from the Regex Tag Wiki: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Comment: $content = file_get_contents('whatever.html');
// do sth with $content here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following regex:

```
(<\?php\s*(?:include|require|include_once|require_once)\s*.*['"](.*)['"]\s*;*\s*\?>)
```

to capture both the whole include text and  `whatever.html` so you could easy replace it with your custom code ( Of course when working on true file you should create backup before using it in case you want to modify original files).

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hG1jF5/3)**

Comment: Thanks, how can you get this into a php string without the quotes breaking?

Comment: @frankpulsar Probably http://regex101.com/r/hG1jF5/5 should work. It it's not ask new question with detail explanation not in this question